# Shamir's Secret Sharing using Bignum or Bigint or ....?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, biginteger, bignum

I've got a generic cryptographic implementation using OpenSSL's BIGNUM library in C.  Standard decryption is working fine, but i would also like to implement Shamir's secret sharing (SSS).

The problem i've run across is that BIGNUM only supports whole numbers, and as part of the Lagrange interpolation for SSS, i'll need to be multiplying by negative values.

Is there any way to do this?  Otherwise: I *can* do my SSS in another language (python?) so long as it is able to interact with the BIGNUM's produced by OpenSSL.

Any suggestions?  TIA!

Comment: A quick google produced multiple results, including results in C and Java. Why do you want to implement this? For learning purposes I would recommend a language that has big numbers as a language feature (directly or using operator overloading) or at least a good build in type (`BigInteger` in Java). Anything can interact with C, but some languages would be harder to use in this regard than others.

Comment: Don't forget to add the [tag:cryptography] tag to questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

As you look at BIGNUM structure in OpenSSL, you'll find a flag named `neg`. If the BIGNUM object represents a negative number, `neg` will be set to 1. Also, the `bn_mul()` function handles the multiplication by negative number correctly. So you can implement SSS with OpenSSL, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Modular arithmetic (using groups) only provides positive results, so I presume you want to use non-modular arithmetic? In that case you could simply keep a separate variable indicating if the value is negative or not. The outcome of positive multiplication is the same except for the sign bit anyway.

It's not as clean a design as possible, but for a few methods it would probably not matter that much. You could create separate methods that mimic the `BN` methods except for an integer holding the value of the sign (`-1`, `0` or `1`).

Comment: Anybody home? Anything amiss with the answer?